# Reload Js option in react native is not reflecting the changes in JS files

Tags: react-native

Reload JS is not able to show the changes in java script file.earlier this option was working fine.Everytime i need to start ract native packager and install application again

Comment: Are you seeing any error message? Is it downloading the js bundle from your computer?

Comment: There is no error message.it is downloading the js bundle first time install.and when any error comes ,i update and reload js,,it is not reflecting the changes..just showing error again and again.

Comment: Just restart the app in the mobile and check whether it is downloading from the server after the first time install by watching the logs of `react-native start`

Comment: <START> request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot
=false&minify=false
 <END>   request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot
=false&minify=false (163ms)

Comment: I faced exactly same problem before. But, It got solved after restarting the application.

Comment: For me ,i have restarted my system,still its occuring.Everytime i have to uninstall rebuild and install application.I have even changed the simulator

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple possibilities, lets go with one

1. plz check you have created "assets" folder in android/app/src/main

   if you have created then try this command

$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

```
Loading dependency graph . . .
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Copying 299 asset files
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Done copying assets
```

then $ **killall node**

then
    **$ npm start**

```
Loading dependency graph, done
```

then **$ : react-native run-android**